# Woocommerce attributes are somehow added again after removing them in the save_post_product hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a validating function to remove invalid terms from the product after saving.
my problem is that after I successfully removed the invalid terms.
they are re-added so when the update is complete.
the invalid terms are still saved to the post.

```
add_action('save_post_product','validate_product',99,3);

function validate_product($product_id,$post,$update){
    $store_tax = 'pa_store';
    if(get_field('requires_medical_license',$product_id) === true){
         $stores = wc_get_product_term_ids($product_id,$store_tax);
         $invalid_stores = [];
         foreach($stores as $store){
             if(get_field('store_type',$store)!=='pharmacy'){
                 $invalid_stores[] = $store;
             }
         }
         if(!empty($invalid_stores)){
             remove_action('save_post_product','validate_product');
            $success = wp_remove_object_terms($product_id,$invalid_stores,$store_tax);
             add_action('save_post_product','validate_product',99,3);
             $after_stores = wc_get_product_term_ids($product_id,$store_tax);
             // $success // true
             // var_dump($after_stores) // does not contain any invalid stores
             // wp_die() // if I stop the execution here, the terms are successfully removed.
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found workaround that works even better for my intentions.

```
 add_action( 'added_term_relationship','check_validation',1,3);
function check_validation(int $object_id,int $term_id,string $taxonomy){
    if($taxonomy==='pa_store'&&get_field('requires_medical_license',$object_id) === true){
        if(get_field('store_type','term_'.$term_id)!=='pharmacy'){
            wp_remove_object_terms($object_id,$term_id,$taxonomy);
            add_action(
                'admin_notices',
                'admin_notice_product_validation_failed'
            );
        }
    }
}
```

This basically hooks me right after the term relationship was created.
And lets me validate and remove it post creation.
I wish there was a cleaner way to do it so we dont have to call the DB twice.

but that is all I could find.